# Raise an event when Property Changed using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, propertychanged

I am working in C# and I have an object which I can only access using `Reflection` (for some personal reasons). So, when I need to set some value to one of its properties I do as below:

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property = this.Parent.GetType().GetProperty("SomeProperty");
object someValue = new object(); // Just for example
property.SetValue(this.Parent, someValue, null);
```

And, to get its value I use the method `GetValue`.

My question is: **Is there a way to fire an event when the property changes using Reflection?**

Comment: Does this class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?  Calling SetValue should use the properties setter.

Comment: @cadrell0, No, Im afraid It doesnt

Comment: @Dante, did you find a solution for this ? I'm trying to trigger a notification event when Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture value is changed which is similar to your question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to fire an event when the property changes using Reflection?

Not unless the property setter itself raises it, no. There's nothing "watching" for all properties changing, and raising events when they do.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I guees I need to take another approach then

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inotifychanged in WPF application.. automatically change the property value when some event occured related to property